# given a list of 3 dimension what is the best approach to find the highest sum

Tags: sorting, multithreaded

We are given a file of three columns
the first is player name
the second is game item name
the third is the price of the game item while it bought by the player

items may repeat ror the dame player with different prices

what is the best parallel approach in time and space to get  the player name with the highest sum of all items prices while keeping the most  5 valued items in descending order in ascending alphabeticaly

my attempt is to read the file  in parallel and then each node should read its chunk line by line and sum the total of prices for each player and always update the most valued 5 items to the above constraint

this is just my logical analysis of the problem but i don't know if i am correct

Comment: I can't find a useful meaning for anything but the first part of `keeping the most
5 valued items in descending order in ascending alphabetically`.

Comment: i want to say if two itels have the same price then the ordering is alphabetical

Comment: `i want to say …` Do! In your question: [Edit](/posts/165783/edit) it. Pay more attention to spelling. This looks a programming question: Please find [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on/129632#129632)